# What search entry should I use to get a list of all answers ever posted on IPS, arranged by votes?

Tags: support

I am looking to use search to see whether many downvoted answers with negative score still remain undeleted, or not. What search entry should I use to get a list of all answers ever posted on IPS, arranged by votes? I need to exclude all questions and deleted answers. I would prefer a search that also allows me to read the actual negative-score answers that remain undeleted, rather than statistics alone. Please also try to link to standard resources on how to use such very specific searches on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Have you heard of specific queries? SE offers a way to look for numbers, you need to set up [your own query](https://data.stackexchange.com/interpersonal/query/new) to access databases

Comment: Thanks for the information @OldPadawan. How to construct the query? Note: I don't know anything about writing software. Also, I would prefer a search that also allows me to read the actual negative-score answers that remain undeleted, rather than statistics alone.

Comment: It's really unnecessary to use SEDE for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of the basic search help is easily accessible in the advanced search tips bar when you're on the search page:

[image: Advanced Search Help bar]

There's more detailed help on the [search help page](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/searching).

For your specific interest, you'll want something like:

```
is:answer score:-100...-1
```

And then click on the "votes" sort order to get [this](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aanswer%20score%3a-100...-1).

You can't see deleted answers, other than your own (if you have 2K+ reputation), but they only come up when you specifically search for them. The query will default to active posts only unless you specify deleted ones.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt and helpful answer @Catija.

Comment: I'd like to correct you on one thing. It requires 2k to view deleted posts regardless of type. ;-P